# execute a process remotely with System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: asp.net, process, system.diagnostics

I'm working on an ASP.net app
I'm trying to execute a process remotely , using System.Diagnostics.Process class

here's my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\TestCommand.exe");

            startInfo.Domain = "myDomain";
            startInfo.UserName = "MyUserName";
            SecureString sec = new SecureString();

            foreach (char item in "MyPassword")
            {
                sec.AppendChar(item);                
            }
            sec.MakeReadOnly();


            startInfo.Password = sec;

            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I keep receiving an exception with the message "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password". 
Im absolutelly sure that i'm submiting my correct username/pwd

Am I missing somethig here?

Tks

Answer (score 1):

Ups, wrong domain  :P